# How to add Gufw to start up?

Tags: gufw

want to know because I am tired of just clicking on the launcher because I just leave my laptop on.  Please help me. Thank You

---

Pass does not apply
When the program is activated

Comment: You do understand that your firewall settings are active without the graphical interface running ? There is no need to run gufw unless you need to change your configuration.

Comment: Please explain about this software

Comment: Pass does not apply When the program is activated

Comment: See http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/firewall-ubuntu-gufw/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Gufw and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW . You otherwise need to ask a more specific question.

Comment: go http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/firewall-ubuntu-gufw/ show Access has been blocked.

Comment: This article is not about this topic----https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already installed gufw, which is basically just a GUI for ufw

```
    sudo apt-get install ufw gufw
```

you can make sure next that your firewall is enabled by running this command:

```
   sudo ufw enable
```

and you can check you firewall status after restart using this command:

```
   sudo ufw status verbose
```

By all means, you can open Gufw and unlock the settings and check if all is ok. After that you can close Gufw, the firewall will still be active and running in background.

If you plan to secure your computer way beyond the simple ufw firewall you can visit [this link](http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-secure-ubuntu-1204-lts-server-part-1-basics) to learn how to secure a linux server or a workstation. You should pay a special attention to the following steps present [in this tutorial](http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-secure-ubuntu-1204-lts-server-part-1-basics):

- Protect su by limiting access only to admin group
- Harden network with sysctl settings
- Scan logs and ban suspicious hosts - DenyHosts and Fail2Ban
- Check for rootkits - RKHunter and CHKRootKit